# Importing a Big xml file to neo4j embedded in Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I have an very big XML file with ~50m lines.

I am trying to create a Neo4j Graph Database of the XML file.

I am using Java in NetBeans IDE to:

1) Import XML data in the Java application.
2) Create a Neo4j graph database with the data.

For step 1, I am using SAX parser which gives me the data by one xml tag at a time.

The XML tags are:

1) A conference paper. (The outer tag)
2) The conference it belongs to. (Inner tag)
3) The authors of the conference paper. (Inner tag)

I need the following nodes and relationship while creating the Neo4j graph database.

1) Create a new node for each paper. (Duplicates cannot occur as each paper is described only once) 
2) Create a new node for each conference. (No duplicates should exist the graph) 
3) Create a new node for each author. (No duplicates should exist the graph)

In the relationships, each paper should be connected to its conference and each author should be connected to the papers written by the author.

Example:

[image]

I know this is a very specific question but I am not expecting a perfect answer to my question, I am just looking for approaches towards solving it.

**I am completely new to Neo4j.**

How should I go about this problem? I was advised to use Batch Insertion, but is it possible to use it while inserting 1 value (node) at a time and also checking the conditions and constraints in the graph db while inserting it.

This is what I am thinking of: 
If the tag already has a node (If a conference node already exists, don't create the node, just find the node by its ID and link the paper to it) or create the node, if it doesn't exists (Create a new node for the conference if it doesn't exist and then link the paper to the new node). Same process for paper and authors. (If the author does not exist, create a new node and link the author to the paper or if the author already exist, find the node and link that node to the paper). How much time would this process take? Is it feasible to go through with this approach.

What other options do I have towards solving this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Let's say your data has unique IDs for papers, authors, and conferences. A minimal neo4j data model might then look something like this (which mimics the model illustrated in your question):

```
(:Conf {id: 111, name: 'XYZ Conference 2016'})-[:HAS_PAPER]->
  (:Paper {id: 222, name: 'The Theory of Everything'})-[:HAS_AUTHOR]->
  (:Author {id: 333, name: 'Albert Einstein IV'})
```

If your neo4j client fills in 3 [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) with info on each paper like this:

```
{
  "conf": {"id": "111", "name": "XYZ Conference 2016"},
  "authors": [
    {"id": "333", "name": "Albert Einstein IV"},
    {"id": "444", "name": "Isaac Newton XVIII"}],
  "paper": {"id": "222", "name": "The Theory of Everything"}
}
```

Then the query for creating the nodes and relationships for a paper would look something like this:

```
MERGE (c:Conf {id: {conf}.id, name: {conf}.name} ) 
CREATE (c)-[:HAS_PAPER]->(p:Paper {paper})
FOREACH (x IN {authors} |
  MERGE (a:Author {id: x.id, name: x.name})
  CREATE (p)-[:HAS_AUTHOR]->(a))
```

NOTE 1: The above `MERGE` clauses assume that conference and author names never change. If they can change, then the `name` properties should be set in separate `SET` clauses, or you could get multiple nodes for the same ID.

NOTE 2: When concurrent updates are are possible, it is also possible to get duplicate nodes with the same ID, even when everyone uses `MERGE`. Therefore, to prevent duplicate nodes, you should create [uniqueness constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#query-constraints-unique-nodes) for `:Conf(id)`, `:Author(id)`, and `:Paper(id)`. neo4j will abort a query that violates such a constraint.

NOTE 3: The `MERGE` clause does not support setting all the properties directly from a "map", as the `CREATE` clause does, so `MERGE` clauses have to specify each property separately.

Comment: you should also have constraints in place on :Conf(id), :Author(id) and :Paper(id)

Comment: Thanks a lot of the answer @cybersam 
In between the time where I asked the question and your answer, I have done something like this, where I have created unique constraints on the node and and then used MERGE to inset the data into the Graph and MATCH to get which paper belongs to which author and also, which conference belongs to which paper. 
I think it is similar to what you have suggested, but I am getting an estimated time of 4 days for my code to finish.
Is there is any other approach (like batch insertion) which I can use for my code to run a little faster.

Comment: I cannot really comment without seeing your code. For example, I'm not sure why you need `MATCH` clauses. This probably deserves another Question to SO.